# How do I know if I am on Amazon EC2 account free plan

Tags: amazon-ec2

How do I know if I am on Amazon EC2 account free plan? I just opened a new account yesterday and Amazon talks about a free plan for micro instances. But I don't see an indication in the console user interface that I am on a free plan.

Comment: can someone care to post, why there is a down vote on the question.

Comment: Because we're systems administrators, not the EC2 support desk.

Comment: Kindly don't get me wrong. I thought this was a forum to get help and I feel this is a genuine question, this has nothing to do with other participants being system administrators or developers. I would probably abstain, if I think the question is genuine. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: In that case you are mistaken. Firstly, this site is not a forum (see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq)). Secondly, we are very strict about the questions that people ask here. We only permit questions that are applicable to a wider audience that will be of use to people far into the future. Thirdly, we don't permit questions that have a very, very narrow scope (such as this one).

Comment: AWS offers a free plan and as a new user I would definitely want to know if I am on that plan and I truly believe it is applicable for all new users of EC2. If I can post in either in stackoverflow or serverfault where am I supposed to pose these questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you're a new signup and only running a micro instance, you're a free user. The console itself doesn't indicate; but if you go to 'account activity' and expand the EC2 section, it'll indicate your current expenses under the free tier.